# How do I find the length of an object?

Tags: javascript, json

```
"namelist":{
            "name":"xyz",
            "version":"1.0.0"
         }
```

How to find the length of the two values inside the `namelist`?

Comment: string length or something else?

Comment: `Object.keys(obj.namelist).length`?

Comment: Can you give an example of things you have tried?

Comment: You can use javascript for that task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find size of object (i.e total number of attributes in object)like this:

```
namelist = { "name":"xyz", "version":"1.0.0" }
var size = Object.keys(namelist).length;
console.log(size);
```

> Output: 2

For getting size of value of `name` attribute ( e.g size of "xyz" in your case)

```
console.log(namelist.name.length)
```

> Output: 3

For getting size of value of `version` attribute( e.g size of "1.0.0" in your case)

```
console.log(namelist.version.length)
```

> Output: 5

Answer (score 1):

Get the keys as an array using Object.keys, and take the length of that array:

```js
const obj = {
  namespace: {
    key1: 'whatever',
    key2: 'whatever2',
  }
}

const keys = Object.keys(obj.namespace) // ['key1', 'key2']
const keysLength = keys.length // 2
```